# jooQ spring boot Multiple Schema(Read Write Split)

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jooq

I want to use jooQ with spring boot. I have master slave architecture, so I want to use  jooQ with master slave architecture (master for write & slave for read).

How should I proceed. now i am using pom.xml to configure jooQ

```xml
<configuration>
    <jdbc>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>${datasource.primary.url}</url>
        <user>${datasource.primary.username}</user>
        <password>${datasource.primary.password}</password>
    </jdbc>
    <generator>
        <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <excludes/>
            <inputSchema>jpa</inputSchema>
        </database>
        <generate>
            <deprecated>false</deprecated>
        </generate>
        <target>
            <packageName>com.gensrc.model</packageName>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

and then just Autowiring the DSLContext

But how do I change my code now.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I suspect you have two users or schemas or databases (one for writing and one for reading), but how do they relate, and what do you expect jOOQ to do? - *"But how do I change my code now"* - what code do you mean?

Comment: I have two different Databases On two different servers. Both are replicas of each other. One is used for Reading(slave) & other is used for write(master). I want to route all my write queries to master & all my read queries to slave.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments:

> I want to route all my write queries to master & all my read queries to slave.

I'm not so sure that this hard distinction between write=master, read=slave will be a good idea. Sometimes, you will probably need to read from the master as well within the same transaction boundaries (i.e. read back uncommitted data), in case of which sending the read query to a slave would yield wrong results.

So, the best place to implement this routing would be to have separate `DataSource` instances and inject them into jOOQ accordingly. You'll then be separating master and slave in your service layer explicitly, transparently for jOOQ.

You could, of course, implement your original requirement by using a jOOQ [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) and by providing jOOQ with the right JDBC `Connection` depending on the query type ([`ExecuteContext.type()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteContext.html#type--)), but again, I think this will break quite soon.

Comment: Yes, I understand that approach is basically creating two data soucre & then inject into jooQ. But how do I inject Data Source to jooQ. I am currently autowiring the DSLContext which is taking primary data souce. I have tried to initialize the DSLContext using @Qualifier but it is not getting initialized. Can you share the code for same?

Comment: Yes thats a common scenario to use master for read write transasction, that will also be done if I am able to inject Data Soucre to JooQ DSLContext.

Comment: @AnkitBansal: You have a lot of questions :) But none of them are in your actual question text. Would you mind asking a new question on Stack Overflow for each problem statement that you have? If in doubt, here's a handy page explaining how Stack Overflow works: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @LukasEder we are using 2 dslContext. `Writer` is default dslContext provided by Spring auto-configure. `Reader` dslContext we are creating via deriving existing configuration of default context with different `DataSource`. 

Just wanted to know, is there any best practice, because it is using same object of ExecuteListener, TransactionListener etc. 

As our reader datasource can't execute transaction, is it ok to have `SpringTransactionProvider` for reader? Why Im asking, I want minimal configuration.

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti: Why not ask a new question?

Comment: @LukasEder here it is https://stackoverflow.com/q/68260908/7857701