# Best practices on configuring 2 DataSource with Jooq

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

We are splitting read and write side of our DB queries. Achieved that as mentioned [jooQ spring boot Multiple Schema(Read Write Split)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255491/jooq-spring-boot-multiple-schemaread-write-split)

**Our config:**

- We are using 2 `dslContext`. `Writer` is default dslContext provided by [SpringBoot auto-configure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jooq/JooqAutoConfiguration.html).
- `Reader` dslContext we are creating via deriving existing configuration of default context with different DataSource.

```java
public DSLContext getReaderContext(@Qualifier("readerDataSource") DataSource readerDataSource, DSLContext dslContext) {
    return DSL.using(dslContext.configuration().derive(readerDataSource));
}
```

So Reader context is using same instance of `ExecuteListener`, `TransactionListener`, `Settings` in the configuration. This is to reduce manual configuration.

**Other configuration that we tried:**

```java
public DSLContext getReaderContext(@Qualifier("readerDataSource") DataSource readerDataSource, JooqProperties jooqProperties, Settings settings) {
    return DSL.using(readerDataSource, jooqProperties.determineSqlDialect(readerDataSource), settings)
}
```

Here all configuration instance is different. But manual work is there. Like there is no `ExecuteListener`(Default `JooqExceptionTranslator`) in reader context, so if required we have to add manual configuration.

1. Is there any best practice for configuring 2 or more dslContext?
2. Also our reader datasource can't execute transaction (AWS Read Replica), as we are using same config as writer, is it ok to have SpringTransactionProvider for reader?

Comment: Why are you injecting qualified `DataSource` instead of injecting qualified `DSLContext`?

Comment: As we want default (Writer) `dslContext` with default config, and spring auto-configure will not create bean of `dslContext` (writer) if I configure a `dslContext` (reader) due to `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(DSLContext.class)`. We couldn't find any other solution to it.

Comment: So we created a wrapper class which is a spring `@Component`. This wrapper class  is having 2 beans (read & write) of `dslContext` and logic which one to pickup.

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti have you managed solve this issue?

Comment: @JayAhn nope, we went ahead with this, configuring 2 data sources then configuring 2 DSL context